# Internationalization issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

Hi all i am working on internationalization using spring mcv. But i am not able to perform language change. please help in that. here is my servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <!-- <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> -->
</bean>


<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and this is my file directory structure :
[image]

and this is language selection menu :

```html
<span style="float: right"> 
    <a href="?language=en">en</a> |
    <a href="?language=ge">ge</a> |
    <a href="?language=it">it</a>
   </span>
```

please help me to solve the language selection issues 
why its not working to me ? please provide the suggestion.

***New edited Servlet.xml***

-->

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things,

Please use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` instead of `ResourceBundleMessageSource`

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource "> 
   <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages"></property>
</bean>
```

then you have to move your resource bundle files from current src/main/resources to your WEB-INF.

Also add relevant bundles as per your requirements like,

messages_en, messages_gt, messages_it in your WEB-INF.

EDIT :

Also I suspect that you need following,

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Instead of,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is because while changing the language you are not invoking any Controller mapping. Hence it is not getting intercepted by the interceptor and your language is not getting changed.

Comment: giveing me - HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is error

Comment: if you add properties file in src/main/resources or you add in WEB-INF it doesn't make any difference. if i make "it" as default then it will work same as "en". but its not iterating right now i want to fix that issue only.

Comment: @DhruvGurjar can you update your question and show what all you did based on suggestion. It should work fine.

Comment: i change on your suggestion for "ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" but if i move properties to WEB-INF or if its at src/java/resource the it is not make any difference it work fine with both. but on the basis of language param its not working its still considering "en" properties which is default one. but not Italian or German.

Comment: first tell me whether you moved to WEB-INF as suggested and tried? How many message files you have? I want you to have 4. one messages.properties, messages_en.properties and 2 for others.

Comment: yes i tried on your suggestion and its inside the WEB-INF right now . but i have 3 message file not messages.properties file just language files.

Comment: @DhruvGurjar check with my updated answer please. Also you will require messages.properties as you have defined it as your basename.

Comment: i made changes as per your suggestion but its still not working i also made message.properties file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131489/discussion-between-scanqr-and-dhruv-gurjar).

Answer (score 0):

Register the *SessionLocaleResolver*

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>
```

Register "*LocaleChangeInterceptor*" interceptor, and invoke it
    to the handler mappings that need to support those languages

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And (this is what you're missing)

```
<!-- Register the messages_.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
              class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" /><!-- value="messages" as the prefix is messages_.properties -->
    </bean>
```

Also it's not magically translating any texts on the page you'll still need to reference the text in the *.properties* files, as they're the ones that will be translated:

For e.g :

`messages_en.properties` contains :

```
messages.text = My name
```

`messages_ge.properties` contains

```
messages.text = Ich heise
```

Then you output this text on the target page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
 ...
 ...
  <h3> your message : <spring:message code="messages.text" text="default text" /> </h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working to me. and there is also i register message source property but there is something wrong so its not displaying in the code.i tried lots of site to do this but still its not working why ?